# How to get proportions of levels of a variable?

Tags: r

```
c1 <- rep(1,47)
c2 <- rep(0,53)
c <- c(c1,c2)
cweight <- c(1:100)
```

I would like to know proportion of 1 and 0 in c using weights. when I use wtd.table command I get frequencies. I want fraction or better percentages.

```
install.packages("weights")
library(weights)
wtd.table(c,weight=cweight)
```

this is the output I get.

```
wtd.table(c,weight=cweight)
  0    1 
3922 1128
```

I want percentages. I didn't get simple way to do this though it looks like very simple information about the variable.

Comment: as a side comment, it's not considered a good practice to have variables (here `c`), named like functions (`c` too) ;)

Comment: Thanks. I realized it after posting. Will take care in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
x <- wtd.table(c,weight=cweight)
x / sum(x)
```

Also, It does not seem to me a need to use `wtd.table()`. Do this:

```
x <- table(c)
x / sum(x)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I need wtd.table() because in actual data I am working on I have weights.